# Parsing text to phonemes - Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, algorithm, sorting, parsing

I have a question which I've been researching extensively these past few days, as you can tell by the title has to do with a text to speech type algorithm for parsing strings into phonemes.

I don't plan on using this for text to speech, mostly just text analysis for an upcoming project I'll be working on. I found some helpful information here:

http://www.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a021929.pdf

Using this information, I was hoping to create a similar tool. Here is the way the software mentioned above works:

Essentially, starting with the first character of a string, we check the characters to the left and the right of it.

*(for characters in the beginning of a word, the left character would be a blank space)*

We set up rules based on the 44 English phonemes, and the graphemes that fit under each phoneme.

Here is where I got the data to make up these rules:
http://www.boardman.k12.oh.us/userfiles/363/Phonological%20Awareness/44Phonemes.pdf - which I believe are different than some of the rules in the article before this one.

Here is an example of the rule object I've created thus far:

```
        var rules_syntax = {
            cons_b: {case:["b", "bb"], pro: "b"},
            cons_d: {case:["d", "dd", "ed"], pro: "d"},
            cons_f: {case:["f", "ph"], pro: "f"},
            cons_g: {case:["g", "gg"], pro: "g"},
            cons_h: {case:["h"], pro: "h"},
            cons_j: {case:["j", "g", "ge", "dge"], pro: "j"},
            cons_k: {case:["c", "k", "ck", "ch", "cc", "que"], pro: "k"},
            cons_l: {case:["l", "ll"], pro: "l"},
            cons_m: {case:["m", "mm", "mb"], pro: "m"},
            cons_n: {case:["n", "nn", "kn", "gn"], pro: "n"},
            cons_p: {case:["p", "pp"], pro: "p"},
            cons_r: {case:["r", "rr", "wr"], pro: "r"},
            cons_s: {case:["s", "se", "ss", "ci", "ce", "sc"], pro: "s"},
            cons_t: {case:["t", "tt", "ed"], pro: "t"},
            cons_v: {case:["v", "ve"], pro: "v"},
            cons_w: {case:["w"], pro: "w"},
            cons_y: {case:["y", "oi", "io"], pro: "y"},
            cons_z: {case:["z", "zz", "ze", "se", "x"], pro: "z"},

            cons_diag_th:       {case:["th"], pro: "th"},
            cons_diag_th_voice: {case:["th"], pro: "thh"},
            cons_diag_ng:       {case:["ng", "n"], pro: "n"},
            cons_diag_sh:       {case:["sh", "ss", "ch", "ti", "ci"], pro: "sh"},
            cons_diag_ch:       {case:["ch", "tch"], pro: "ch"},
            cons_diag_zh:       {case:["ge", "s"], pro: "zh"},
            cons_diag_wh:       {case:["wh"], pro: "w"},

            shor_vowe_a: {case: ["a", "au"], pro: "a"},
            shor_vowe_e: {case: ["e", "ea"], pro: "e"},
            shor_vowe_i: {case: ["i"], pro: "i"},
            shor_vowe_o: {case: ["o", "a", "au", "aw", "ough"], pro: "o"},
            shor_vowe_u: {case: ["u", "o"], pro: "u"},

        }
```

Hopefully this is enough for you to get the idea.

The first article has the below rules as well, which I have not entirely figured out how to implement. - **Any suggestions for this would be great**

> '#' One or more vowels
>
> '*' (star) One or more consonants
>
> '*' (circle) One of B, D, V, G, J, L, M, N, R, W, and Z: a voiced consonant
>
> '$' One consonant followed by an E or I
>
> '%' One of (ER, E, ES, ED, ING, ELY): a suffix
>
> '&' One of (S, C, G, Z, X, J, CH, SH): a sibilant
>
> '@' One of (T, S, R, D, L, Z, N, J, TH, CH, SH): a consonant influencing the
>   sound of a following long u (cf. rule and mule)
>
> '^' One consonant
>
> '+' One of (E, I, Y): a front vowel
>
> ':' Zero or more consonants

My first question is this:

**Does anyone find this to be an adequate way to approach these rules? Suggestions please.**

Moving on,

Once we know what the primary character is, as well as the character to the left and to the right, we check all of the rules that apply to this character group. The first article posted explained

> The translation algorithm scans input text from left to right and, **for each character scanned**, sequentially **searches the rules pertinent** to that character until it finds one whose **left-hand side matches the text at the correct position.**

This is where I'm currently stuck. I have my code setup so that it can collect all the rules that a character group applies to, but once I have this i'm not sure how to chose which one is the correct phoneme. For instance, I've been using the word 'cautious' as an example. the "au" combination in this word fits under the "a" rule as well as the "o" rule.

this would create the a sound as in laugh or it would create the o sounds as in taught. Clearly the o as in taught would be the correct answer, but how I can I make my code check for this?

**how I can I determine which phoneme is the correct to use here?**

Is this where that second set of rules that I haven't used yet comes into play? If so, how would you suggest using these rules to eliminate / narrow the rules that apply?

I've been sitting on this concept for a while, I'm no professional but I'd like to get anyone's feed back. If more details are necessary please let me know. Here is the code I have this far:

```
    var test01 = function(word)
    {
        var arr = [];
        var arr2 = [];

        //for every letter in the word
        for(var x = 0; x < word.length; x ++)
        {
            //grab the letter
            var index = word[x];
            var pert = [];
            //push the letter to an array
            arr.push(index);

            //create an object which holds the neighboring letters
            var pro = new Object();
            pro.left = word[x - 1];
            pro.org = index;
            pro.right = word[x + 1];
            //store this object in an array
            arr2.push(pro);


            //check to see if any spaces exist (undefined) and replace them with a ""
            for(b in pro)
            {
                if(!pro[b])
                {
                    pro[b] = "";
                }
            }

            //loop through each letter object
            for(var y = 0; y < arr2.length; y ++)
            {
                var letter = arr2[y];
                letter.rules = [];

                //loop through each rule that exists
                for (z in rules_syntax)
                {
                    var rule = rules_syntax[z];

                    //for each rule, loop through its graphemes
                    for(var a = 0; a < rule.case.length; a ++)
                    {

                        var grapheme = rule.case[a];
                        //combine the original letter, and the letter to the left
                        var letterCheck = letter.left + letter.org;

                        //check if the above combo (left + original) exists in the list of graphemes
                        if(letterCheck === grapheme)
                        {
                            //here is where I would put any other conditions to check for any other rules.
                            pert.push(rule.pro);
                            letter.rules.push(rule.pro);
                        } 

                        if(letter.org === grapheme)
                        {
                            //here is where I would put any other conditions to check for any other rules.
                            pert.push(rule.pro);
                            letter.rules.push(rule.pro);

                        } 
                    }
                }
            }

            console.log(pert);

        }
    }

    test01("cautious");
```

And here is the last line of the output

```
(16) ["k", "k", "a", "o", "a", "o", "u", "t", "sh", "i", "y", "o", "u", "u", "s", "zh"]
```

Any responses are appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: The article says (and you quote it) that the algorithm "sequentially searches the rules pertinent to that character". In other words, it tries the rules one at a time in the order they are presented, and the first one which matches wins.

Comment: I appreciate the response but this can't be the case. When the word taught is passed through, the function (if the function were to work how you suggest) then when the AU combo is matched with the A sounds as in "laugh" it would end, because A occurs before O. Clearly the AU in "taught" is not pronounced the same way as AU in "laugh".

Comment: *Clearly the AU in "taught" is not pronounced the same way as AU in "laugh".* Are you sure about that? Have you run the code and listened to its output? Having used one of the early text-to-speech boxes that implemented that NRL algorithm, I can attest that it made some pretty funny mistakes. "Computer," for example, was pronounced "com poo ter". We had to type "compewter" to make it pronounce the word we wanted.

Comment: @JonathanHinds: The rules as printed do not handle 'augh' or 'aught'. I think they also don't manage to distinguish between cough and tough. There are probably other lapses. But that doesn't affect the description of the algorithm.  English is not very regular, unlike some other languages. (Search for  "ghoti".) Note that they were not aiming at 100% accuracy. That paper was written in 1976, and it's remarkable how much they were able to do.

Comment: @jim: what's wrong with compooter? Doesn't it compoot for you? Of course, that was the US Navy, so an American accent was needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're mis-reading Table 2 from the article:

> '#' One or more vowels
>
> '*' (star) One or more consonants
>
> '*' (circle) One of B, D, V, G, J, L, M, N, R, W, and Z: a voiced
>   consonant
>
> '$' One consonant followed by an E or I
>
> '%' One of (ER, E, ES, ED, ING, ELY): a suffix
>
> '&' One of (S, C, G, Z, X, J, CH, SH): a sibilant
>
> '@' One of (T, S, R, D, L, Z, N, J, TH, CH, SH): a consonant
>   influencing the sound of a following long u (cf. rule and mule)
>
> '^' One consonant
>
> '+' One of (E, I, Y): a front vowel
>
> ':' Zero or more consonants

The caption for that table says:

> Special Symbols Appearing in the English-to-IPA Translation Rules

In other words, those aren't rules, but rather descriptions of the notation.

The real rules start on page 51 of the article. As I understand the algorithm, it will start by parsing the 't', and go to the TRULE.ENG section (page 58). The only rule that applies there is `[T]=/T/`. Then it parses the 'a', and looks in ARULE.ENG (page 51). Scanning the rules there, the first one I see that applies is `[AU]=/AO/`, which gives you the "au" as in "taught". From there it goes to the GRULE.ENG list and produces `/ /` for "gh", and then produces `/T/` again for the final "t".

As for "laugh", from the rules I'd say that it's going to pronounce the "au" as in "taught". And because the rule is `#[GH]=/ /`, there will be no other sound. "laugh" will probably sound like "law".

Comment: Thanks for the response Jim. I did see the rules in the later pages. I'll have to implement some examples and test using these rules to see how well they work. Thank you for clarifying this for me.